# xmlDoc.getElementById not working in IE (11)?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm developing a page that load an XML document from the server. 
When using Chrome or Firefox, the function `xmlDoc.getElementById("langueSelect")` will return an xml element. However, on Internet Explorer (11), it return null. 
I've made some research on google and found that the function is supported like here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535155(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <select id="langueSelect">
        <option>1
            <eng>French</eng>
            <fr>Français</fr>
        </option>
        <option>2
            <eng>English</eng>
            <fr>Anglais</fr>
        </option>
    </select>
    <select id="compagnieSelect">
        <option>1
            <eng>ZZZZ</eng>
            <fr>ZZZZ</fr>
            <imgName>LOGO_ZZZZ</imgName>
        </option>
        <option>2
            <eng>TTTT</eng>
            <fr>TTTT</fr>
            <imgName>TTTT</imgName>
        </option>
    </select>
</config>
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function initialize() {

var xmlhttp = null;
//lang = "eng";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Config.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
if (xmlDoc == null) {
    alert("Config.xml est en erreur! Impossible de le charger!")
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Conditions.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlConditions = xmlhttp.responseXML;
if (xmlConditions == null) {
    alert("Conditions.xml est en erreur! Impossible de le charger!")
}


var xmlLangue = xmlDoc.getElementById("langueSelect");
```

}

Comment: You need to post your existing code. What is the value of `xmlDoc`?...

Comment: I dint forget the </config> end tag, its there but not showing up, dont know why.

Comment: Added it for you. Please post the code you are using